# Do you need to know JSTL in JSF or Spring

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

Hi I wanted to know how important is it to learn JSTL ? I mean I could accomplish everything using scriptlet tags in jsp (I know we shouldn't be using scriptlets in JSP pages) . However I am planning to advance from Servlet programming (currently i am only familiar with JSP and servlets) to some other framework possibly JSF,struts or spring  so will learning JSTL come in handy later.. Or is it just an overload ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be handy. As with most of the frameworks you would use JSPs and JSTL for rendering views.
With Spring and other frameworks, you can also use Velocity and freemarker on the view side.
However, learning JSTL surely won't be an overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will. In most web technologies you use JSPs and JSTL in the presentation layer.

Even with JSF, where you don't use JSPs, you can still use the ported JSTL tags.

Answer (score 0):

What you shouldn't be doing is using scriptlets.  It's too easy to start putting logic in the client when you do.

The real beauty of JSTL is that it makes it difficult to put logic in JSPs.

I prefer Velocity as a templating solution these days.  It's better for UI developers, because the template *is* the page.  The visual is there; Java developers add the pieces that actually get the dynamic data later.